# Set SOAP Namepace in .net Core 6 with SOAPCore

Tags: c#, xml, api, .net-core, soap

I am trying to create a SOAP API, I have it running, but when I post an Envelope I get an error stating my namespace is incorrect.

How to I set up my .net Core 6 API Service to expect my desired namespace?

Here is what I have:

My Model:

```
[DataContract(Name = "TestCustomModel", Namespace = "https://myNamespace.com")]
    public class MyCustomModel
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int username { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int orgId { get; set; }
        
        [DataMember]
        public int poolId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string cycleStartDate { get; set; }
    }
```

My Service:

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "https://myNamespace.com")]
    public class SampleService : ISampleService
    {

        
        public string Test(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Method Executed!");
            return s;
        }

        public void XmlMethod(XElement xml)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());
        }

        public MyCustomModel TestCustomModel(MyCustomModel customModel)
        {
            return customModel;
        }

    }
```

My Service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ISampleService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test(string s);

        [OperationContract]
        void XmlMethod(System.Xml.Linq.XElement xml);

        [OperationContract]
        MyCustomModel TestCustomModel(MyCustomModel inputModel);
    }
```

Here is the SOAP I send:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns="https://myNamespace.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:TestCustomModel>
            <userName>USERNAME</userName>
            <password>PASSWORD</password>
            <orgId>123</orgId>
            <poolId>1234</poolId>
            <cycleStartDate>2023-01-01</cycleStartDate>
        </ns:TestCustomModel>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I get this error:
[image]

Based on what I could find, I believe I am setting the namespace in the correct locations, but it still expects tempuri.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to move the namespace declaration from my Service to its interface.

My service:

```
   public class SampleService : ISampleService
    {
        
        public string Test(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Method Executed!");
            return s;
        }

        public void XmlMethod(XElement xml)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());
        }

      
        public MyCustomModel TestCustomModel(MyCustomModel TestCustomModel)
        {
            return TestCustomModel;
        }

    }
```

My Service interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "https://myNamespace.com")]
    public interface ISampleService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test(string s);

        [OperationContract]
        void XmlMethod(System.Xml.Linq.XElement xml);

        [OperationContract]
        MyCustomModel TestCustomModel(MyCustomModel inputModel);
    }
```